# how to execute win cmd from php code?

Tags: php, cmd

I have x.exe in this path: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide` and I want to execute this command: `blastdbcmd -db nr -entry all -outfmt "%g %T"`.

In Windows command line I do:

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide
blastdbcmd -db nr -entry all -outfmt "%g %T"
```

How can I do this from php code. I know `exec($cmd)` or `shell_exec($cmd)` will do it but, how to type the above two statement in `$cmd`?

**Edit1:**
How to save the output of the command in a text file?
I try 3 statement:

```
chdir("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webclient\\db\\nucleotide");
$cmd = "blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt "%g %T" -out $text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt";
exec($cmd);
```

,,

```
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt "%g %T" -out $text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt");
```

,,

```
exec("cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt \"%g %T\" -out $text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt");
```

but, NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt not generated. It seems that the command not executed!

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [`$cmd = ...`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: @Gerald Schneider cmd first time = cd ..... and second time = the command itself, how to execute both?

Comment: Look at `chdir()` [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and then run the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options:

You can prepend the .exe with the path:

```
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt \"%g %T\"");
// don't forget to escape the quotes.
```

If your .exe for some reason really requires you to run it from that directory, change into it with [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) before you execute it.

```
chdir("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide");
exec("blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt \"%g %T\"");
```

Alternatively you can change into the directory and run the command in a single line:

```
exec("cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt \"%g %T\"");
```

Comment: @sara you edited your question so much that the answers become invalid. Don't do that, instead ask a new question with your new problem.

Comment: I mark your answer as the correct answer but seems it not work! maybe I test it wrong. but really it does not work. my edit is the same as my question. I need to know how execute cmd from php and put the output in a text fle.